# Running npm release with webpack causes an error

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

Im following the tutorial from microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-typescript-webpack?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

But when I try to start the programm with npm run release I get following console output:

```
    PS C:\tfs_2020\Developers\User\NetCoreTSWebpack\NetCoreTSWebpack> npm run release                                    
> NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0 release C:\tfs_2020\Developers\User\NetCoreTSWebpack\NetCoreTSWebpack
> webpack --mode=production


webpack not installed

Install webpack to start bundling:
  $ npm install --save-dev webpack

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0 release: `webpack --mode=production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0 release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-18T16_40_09_332Z-debug.log
PS C:\tfs_2020\Developers\User\NetCoreTSWebpack\NetCoreTSWebpack>
```

This is my log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'release'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prerelease', 'release', 'postrelease' ]
5 info lifecycle NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0~prerelease: NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0~release: NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0~release: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0~release: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\tfs_2020\Developers\User\NetCoreTSWebpack\NetCoreTSWebpack\node_modules\.bin;.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Web\External;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Web\External\git
9 verbose lifecycle NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0~release: CWD: C:\tfs_2020\Developers\User\NetCoreTSWebpack\NetCoreTSWebpack
10 silly lifecycle NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0~release: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack --mode=production' ]
11 silly lifecycle NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0~release: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0~release: Failed to exec release script
13 verbose stack Error: NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0 release: `webpack --mode=production`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:321:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\tfs_2020\Developers\User\NetCoreTSWebpack\NetCoreTSWebpack
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "release"
18 verbose node v12.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0 release: `webpack --mode=production`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the NetCoreTSWebpack@1.0.0 release script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have skipped step 3 from the "Configure Webpack and TypeScript" phase, where you needed to run the code below.  Webpack isn't installed according to your output, and step 3 is supposed to install it.

```
npm i -D -E clean-webpack-plugin@3.0.0 css-loader@3.4.2 html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0 mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0 ts-loader@6.2.1 typescript@3.7.5 webpack@4.41.5 webpack-cli@3.3.10
```

Comment: Semms like i had a copy paste error. Thank you for the answer. Do you have a hint for debugging my project now in visual studio? Like some ressource to read?

Comment: @J.Doe I don't have any particular advice regarding Visual Studio - I use a different IDE for development myself.  If this is your first Node project, building a general familiarity with the structure can pay big dividends downstream.